# Saving geocoder results to an array - Closure Trouble

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, closures

Okay, so I have searched a while for a solution to this problem, but I have found nothing specifically on this. 
And before you point me to Google's Terms of Service, please read to the ende of the question!

So here's the idea: 
I want to save the Latitude and Longitude of an address into an array using Google's Geocoder. I managed to calculate all the values correctly, but I just can't seem to save it to the array. I have already used an anonymous function to pass the address to the function, but the saving is still not working. Please help!

Regarding Google's Terms of Service: I know that I may not save this code anywhere and not display it in a Google Map. But I need to save it as a kml-file to feed into a Google Map later. I know, it would be much more convenient to just create the Map, but for other reasons that's not possible.

adressdaten[] is a two-dimensional array with the data of the addresses
This is the code:

```
for (i=1; i<adressdaten.length-1; i++)  {
//Save array-data in String to pass to the Geocoder
var adresse = adressdaten[i][3] + " " + adressdaten[i][4];
var coordinates;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': adresse}, (function (coordinates, adresse) {
        return function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
               coordinates = latLong.lat() + "," + latLong.lng();


        } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        }
    })(coordinates, adresse));
    adressdaten[i][6] = coordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ.  Geocoding is asynchronous.  You need to save the results in the callback function which runs when they are returned from the server.

Something like (not tested)

Updated to use function closure

```
function geocodeAddress(address, i) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
       coordinates = latLong.lat() + "," + latLong.lng();
       adressdaten[i][6] = coordinates;
    } else {
       alert('Geocode of '+address+' was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
for (i=1; i<adressdaten.length-1; i++)  {
  //Save array-data in String to pass to the Geocoder
  var adresse = adressdaten[i][3] + " " + adressdaten[i][4];
  var coordinates;
  geocodeAddress(addresse, i);
```

}

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not work. Your code, even when used with the anonymous function only saves the very last coordinates that were calculated in adressdaten[adressdaten.length][6], so in a field which should not even be touched. I understand that it does that because of the closure and that is exactly the problem I need resolved.

Comment: You didn't say that.  If that is the problem then use a function closure to associate the returned address with the index in the array, answer updated.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Sorry for not posing the question clearly. 
I finally realized the mistake I was making. I tried to implement geocodeAddress() as a separate function, not including it in the scope of the code below. Now everything works fine!