# Google geocoder.geocode, asynchronous variable mapping

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have the following geocode asynchronous method bellow, it works as expected taking in an address from a custom Object Array I have, my problem is mapping of the result back to object[i] that fired that method, see the results only give me back a formatted address which differs from the one i inputed, "Google adds some area codes, changes St to street etc." so when I get these results back I have no way to match the new Lat and Lng coordinates I have gotten to each object due to the asynchronous nature of this method and the results do not return in order, Any idea's what I could do here?

Thanks.

Edit: my thoughts would be creating a way to get the results back in order, change this to Synchronous, not ideal I know and I can't find any examples.

function iterateAndAddress(objArray) {

```
    for(var i=0; i< objArray.length; i++) {

        var address = objArray[i].BillingStreet +' '+objArray[i].BillingCity+' '+objArray[i].BillingCountry;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        console.log('Address = '+address);

        if(geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) { 

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    //console.log(results);
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();  
                    console.log('Address : '+results[0].formatted_address);


                }else if(status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {

                }
                else{

                }
            });  
         }  

    }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving geocoder results to an array - Closure Trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067403/saving-geocoder-results-to-an-array-closure-trouble)

Answer (score 0):

Throw an id into the mix. As well as returning the data, return the id as well and tieing up the information is done and dusted.

...
edit

Ok, so you are making the requests from an object array. Does that array have id keys? If so, then as well as returning lat and long also return the id.

```
var id = objArray[i].id
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

Or whatever id keys you are using.

It might be better to return an array (or object such as)

```
result[i].lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
result[i].lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

As long as you know the records the i ties up with then you have your comparison point.

I must admit, I must be missing the asynchronoucity (word?) of your current method.

Comment: Thanks for the try Rafe I approached this similarly before being relatively new to JS Asynchronous methods, if you used [i] in this instance 1) it would probably be always be the length of the array if it was small, this is because the four loop fires off Multiple  geocoder.geocode methods being asynchronous and by the time the response comes backs out of order infact [i] would be incremented to objArray.length ;),  This is not my issue now though my issue is the matching after all geocoding is done, this does not act as a normal Synchronous method would.

Comment: I know for some things you cna also get it to return the actual request, Could you get it to return the request as well? that way you would have the original names.

Comment: I had a look at the returned results I can't seem to see the request, if I could this would be a work around, not ideal but would do, any idea how it's done:)

Comment: Yes you can get access to orignal address and build it up, like so long_name: "Santa Teresa Boulevard"
short_name: "Santa Teresa Blvd" Still not the best solution but thanks for getting me thinking.

Comment: Actually, this only allows me to choose between Googles short and long names, it still packs in other data, maybe could sort by area code but messy

Comment: I was just thinking of doing it by state and area code. If your addresses are not so close as to have the same details.

Comment: Unfortunately Raff there could be potentially hundreds of addresses, sent on my dilemma to a friend of mine if he has a solution ill be sure to post.