# closure geocode loop multiple markers variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I am stuck with a javascript issue with Google maps.

The code was constructed to work with Lat and long, but I need to convert it to work with Zipcodes, which means I need to implement geocoding.

In the code below everything operates and I have tried to cut down the fat.

The first var is set latLng (based on provided lat lng.

Right below that is the code I am struggling with.  I have reduced it as much as i can.

I can get into it, but I can't pull the results out of it.

It was wrapped in a function but that part is gone so I could minimize the what i was looking at.

It also works with clustering which operates fine.

So the issue is feeding the marker position (latLng) with (latLngRaw) will change that to something better (testing).

I have looked at the closure examples and I cannot see the solution.  It seems there are a few touch points that are escaping me, possibly because I am restricted on altering the code (minimal code change).

the entire block of code is below but the action happens inside the spinnerUp function

var latlng
var marker
var geocoder

are the problems.

Thanks in advance for help and let me know if I need to clarify some of the exiting functionality.

```
var geocoder;
google.load('maps', '3', {
other_params: 'sensor=false'
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;


    function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.252,-96.009);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    spinnerUp(i);
    }

        function spinnerUp() {

            var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[i];

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data_mapper.latitude,data_mapper.longitude);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data_mapper.zip}, function(results, status) {
                 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     var latLngRaw = results[0].geometry.location;
                     alert(latLngRaw);
                     }
                     });






            var boxText = "<div>";
            var boxText = "<img src='http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cute-baby-photo-27.jpg' width='75' align='left'/>";
                boxText += data_mapper.title + "<br>" + data_mapper.address + "<br>" + data_mapper.city + ", " + data_mapper.zip;
                boxText += "</div>";

            var iconColorSpecial = "/images/main/HeartDove.png";

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng, icon:iconColorSpecial});

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                    content: boxText
                                                    ,disableAutoPan: false
                                                    ,maxWidth: 0
                                                    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)            
                                                    ,zIndex: null
                                                    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                                                    ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                                                    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                                                    ,isHidden: false
                                                    ,pane: "floatPane"
                                                    ,enableEventPropagation: false});


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map, this);});
        markers.push(marker);       
        }

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

(Updated):  Here is is a generated test data set (I am testing the first respondent's code suggestions).

```
var data = { "count": 3,"locationstuff": [{"locaid": 1, "title": "test", "address": "545 Ave A ", "city": "Plattsmouth", "state": "NE", "zip": "68048", "longitude": -95.89, "latitude": 41.01, "iconSpecial": 0},{"locaid": 2, "title": "test2", "address": "14100 Crawford St. ", "city": "Boys Town", "state": "NE ", "zip": "68010", "longitude": -96.13, "latitude": 41.25, "iconSpecial": 0},{"locaid": 3, "title": "test3", "address": "1005 South 76th St. ", "city": "Omaha", "state": "NE", "zip": "68114 ", "longitude": -96.03, "latitude": 41.25, "iconSpecial": 0}]}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving geocoder results to an array - Closure Trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067403/saving-geocoder-results-to-an-array-closure-trouble)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After shuffling things around and tidying up a bit, I ended up with this :

```
var map, 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
    infoWinOpts = {
        content: null,//added later
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
        zIndex: null,
        closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
        closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
    };

function spinnerUp(data_mapper) {
    infoWinOpts.content = [
        "<div><img src='http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cute-baby-photo-27.jpg' width='75' align='left'/>",
        data_mapper.title + "<br>" + data_mapper.address + "<br>" + data_mapper.city + ", " + data_mapper.zip,
        "</div>"
    ].join('');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: data_mapper.latLng
        icon: "/images/main/HeartDove.png"
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWinOpts);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    return marker;
}

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.252, -96.009);
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var markers = [];
    for (var responseCount=0, latLngRaw, i=0; i < data.count; i++) {
        var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[i];
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': data_mapper.zip
        }, (function(data_mapper) {
            return function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latLngRaw = results[0].geometry.location;
                    //alert(latLngRaw);
                    data_mapper.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latLngRaw.latitude, latLngRaw.longitude);//or something similar
                    markers.push( spinnerUp(data_mapper) );
                }
                responseCount++;
                if(responseCount == data.count) {
                    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
                }
            }
        })(data_mapper));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

*untested*

There's a couple of tricky aspects :

- the need to form a closure at each pass of the for loop, to trap `data_mapper`.
- the need to maintain `responseCount` which is tested to determine when to call `new MarkerClusterer()`.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a run.  In the meantime, I have found a really simple way to manage this (for anyone that lands here in the future).  I found a database of zipcodes and their lat/lng coords. I created a second table, loaded the data, then created a view which I query to get everything I need as one data source eliminating the asych geocoding need for each record (huge burden relief).  But other coders that have to go the geocoding route would find the situations and examples here helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Geocoding is asynchronous, you need to *use* the returned coordinates in the call back routine:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data_mapper.zip}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latLngRaw = results[0].geometry.location;
    alert(latLngRaw);
  }
});
```

You probably also need to pass the argument (i) into the spinnerUp function:

```
function spinnerUp() {
  var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[i];
```

This might work, not tested, no data:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function createMarker(latLng, data_mapper) {
    var boxText = "<div>";
    var boxText = "<img src='http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cute-baby-photo-27.jpg' width='75' align='left'/>";
        boxText += data_mapper.title + "<br>" + data_mapper.address + "<br>" + data_mapper.city + ", " + data_mapper.zip;
        boxText += "</div>";

    var iconColorSpecial = "/images/main/HeartDove.png";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng, icon:iconColorSpecial});

    // these look like arguments to construct an InfoBubble...
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)            
        ,zIndex: null
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false});

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map, this);});
   markers.push(marker);       
}

function geocodeAddress(data_mapper, index) {
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       var latLngRaw = results[0].geometry.location;
       createMarker(latLngRaw, data_mapper);
    } else { alert("Geocoder failed: "+status); ]
 });

function spinnerUp(index) {
  var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[index];
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data_mapper.latitude,data_mapper.longitude);
  geocodeAddress(data_mapper, index);
}
```

Not sure why you have your "spinnerUp" function local to the initialize function.

Comment: Thanks for the help...but the example doesn't work and it is radically different from what i have working.  I think I will just geocode the zip then go through the spinnerup function without the baggage. Again thanks for your help.