# Save the location of geocoder into array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array (tab) of addresses and I wanna save the location of all addresses into a another multidimensional (test) I have tried this code but it doesn't work

```js
var test = [];
for (var i = tab.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var r=[];
  geocoder.geocode({address: tab[i].toString()},function (result,status){
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      r.push(result[0].geometry.location.k);
      r.push(result[0].geometry.location.D);
    }else{
      r.push(0);
      r.push(0);
    };
  })
  test.push(r);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving geocoder results to an array - Closure Trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067403/saving-geocoder-results-to-an-array-closure-trouble)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create/push the temporarily array `r` inside the geocode-callback:

```js
var tab   =['berlin','paris','rome'],
    test  =[],
    geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
for (var i = tab.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  
  geocoder.geocode({address: tab[i].toString()},function (result,status){
    var r=[];
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      r.push(result[0].geometry.location.lat());
      r.push(result[0].geometry.location.lng());
    }else{
      r.push(0);
      r.push(0);
    };
    test.push(r);
    //print resulting array
    if(test.length===tab.length){
      document.body.textContent='[\n ['+test.join('],\n [').toString()+']\n]';
    }
  })
  
}
```

```css
body{white-space:pre;font-family:monospace;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

Also note: to access the `lat` and `lng` of a LatLng use the build-in methods with the similar name. The properties `k` and `D` will not be stable across the API-versions.

But there is an issue with the array-approach:
There is no guarantee that the results arrive in the desired order, you will not be able to get a relation between a address and the returned location.

Another approach, which uses an object(using the addresses as keys):

```js
var tab   ={'berlin':null,'paris':null,'rome':null},
    geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
    
for (var k in tab) {
  
  geocoder.geocode(
     {
        address: k.toString()
     },
     (function(address){
       return function(result,status){
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        tab[address]={
                lat:result[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                lng:result[0].geometry.location.lng()
               }
       }
       
       document.body.textContent=JSON.stringify(tab);
      } 
     }(k)));  
}
```

```css
body{white-space:pre;font-family:monospace;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```